# Antlr parser doesn't generate all expected code

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr3

I have a grammar as roughly defined in [Tutorial for walking ANTLR ASTs in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887205/tutorial-for-walking-antlr-asts-in-c):

```
grammar Test; 

options 
{
language = 'CSharp3'; 
output=AST; 
} 
public expr : mexpr (PLUS^ mexpr)* SEMI! 
; 
mexpr 
: atom (STAR^ atom)* 
; 
atom: INT 
; 
//class csharpTestLexer extends Lexer; 
WS : (' ' 
| '\t' 
| '\n' 
| '\r') 
{ $channel = Hidden; } 
; 
LPAREN: '(' 
; 
RPAREN: ')' 
; 
STAR: '*' 
; 
PLUS: '+' 
; 
SEMI: ';' 
; 
protected 
DIGIT 
: '0'..'9' 
; 
INT : (DIGIT)+ 
;
```

This builds, but leaves me with no `parser.expr_result` class which I did expect, and `parser.expr()` returns `AstParserRuleReturnScope` what am I doing wrong? Are it the options? tool commandline options? anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR 3.3 declares rule `expr` like so:

```
    public TestParser.expr_return expr()
```

ANTLR 3.4 declares it like so:

```
    public AstParserRuleReturnScope<object, IToken> expr()
```

Here's the definition of `TestParser.expr_return`:

```
    public class expr_return : ParserRuleReturnScope<IToken>, IAstRuleReturnScope<object>
    {
        private object _tree;
        public object Tree { get { return _tree; } set { _tree = value; } }
    }
```

The `AstParserRuleReturnScope` class appears equivalent to the generated `expr_return` class.